# Trying to imposrt skia_canvas in jupyter with deno kernel fails

Tags: d3.js, jupyter-notebook, deno, skiacanvas

I'm trying out the Deno Jupyter kernel integration.
My specific goal is to use D3 to plot some data in a Jupyter notebook.

My setup is:

- the Deno docker image from Docker Hub :  denoland/deno:ubuntu-1.41.0.
- I installed Jupyter and ran the Deno kernel installation with: deno jupyter --unstable --install.
  I tried out a couple of examples specifically with D3 data plotting and both fail at the same point: when importing from skia_canvas. The examples are here:
- https://blog.logrocket.com/deno-jupyter-notebook-data-dashboard/
- https://blog.jupyter.org/bringing-modern-javascript-to-the-jupyter-notebook-fc998095081e

The code fails at :

```
import {
  createCanvas,
  Image,
  Path2D,
} from "https://deno.land/x/skia_canvas/mod.ts";
```

With:

```
Stack trace:
TypeError: Deno.dlopen is not a function
    at dlopen (https://deno.land/x/plug@1.0.0-rc.3/mod.ts:145:15)
    at eventLoopTick (ext:core/01_core.js:153:7)
    at async https://deno.land/x/skia_canvas@0.5.5/src/ffi.ts:966:10
```

On the skia_canvas repo (https://github.com/DjDeveloperr/skia_canvas) I see they note that their package relies on unstable FFI Api and requires specific run command parameters.

```
deno run --allow-ffi --allow-env --unstable <file>
# or just
deno run -A --unstable <file>
```

However, I am running this in Jupyter so this is not an option I am aware off.

Does anyone have an idea how I can workaround this issue ?